# How to query Failed Email Sends over each business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-views, jobid

I have a request asking to send out an email with the failed send JobId's   (lookback last 2 days) - I would like to automate this process by logging the failed send data to triggered send data extension and then using the same DE for email send.

To begin with, I have started querying the _job data view. Here, I was looking to see the Distinct JobStatus and when I queried I just found 2 status (New & Deleted), there is no mention of cancelled send. I realized cancelled sends have New JobStatus for some reason.

Is there a way to get the failed email send jobid's ?

Thanks in advance!